# Cannot resolve the dependency about yesod-auth-oauth package

Tags: haskell, cabal, yesod

I want to use Yesod web framework with yesod-auth-oauth, but I encountered a dependency problem  while `cabal-dev install`:

```
/Users/kenta/myapp/oryza% cabal-dev install
Resolving dependencies...
cabal: cannot configure yesod-platform-1.0.2. It requires data-default ==0.4.0
For the dependency on data-default ==0.4.0 there are these packages:
data-default-0.4.0. However none of them are available.
data-default-0.4.0 was excluded because authenticate-oauth-1.3.0 requires
data-default ==0.3.*
data-default-0.4.0 was excluded because data-default-0.3.0 was selected
instead
data-default-0.4.0 was excluded because oryza-0.0.0 requires data-default
==0.3.*
```

I don't have any idea of what's wrong.
What I did is just inserting one line in Cabal file:
`yesod-auth-oauth    >= 1.0 && < 1.1`

The default scaffolding works fine, which is created through `yesod init`.

The version information

- yesod-core: 1.0.1
- cabal-dev: 0.9.1 (build with Cabal 1.14.0)
- cabal-install: 0.10.2
- GHC: 7.0.4
- OS: Mac OS X Lion

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks like an overly restrictive upper bound in the authenticate-oauth package. It would be best to follow up directly with the maintainer of that package.

In general, these kinds of issues are a side-effect of following the [Package Versioning Policy](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Package_versioning_policy). Basically, it's a trade-off between having these "refuse to compile" annoyances and more insidious "can't compile" problems.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your advice and I'm sorry I didn't respond to you for a whole year...

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember for sure, but I *think* [my change to the cabal file](https://github.com/rlpowell/yesod) for yesod-auth-oauth fixes this.